# Not a root of unity - how to prove?

Tags: roots, exponentiation, integers

How does one prove that a given complex number is not a root of unity for some positive integer power n? Say, I want to prove that there does not exist a positive integer $n$ such that $(2i)^n = 1$, I could argue that $(2i)^n = 2^ne^{i \pi n/2}$, and we know that $2^n \neq 1$ for any positive integer $n$. But how can we prove that there is no positive integer $n$ such that $2^n = \frac{1}{e^{i \pi n/2}}$?

Comment: OK I think I got it. We know that $2^n \neq 1$ for any integer $n > 0$, and $i^n$ cannot be a fraction for any positive integer.

Comment: For examples like this, $\lvert z^n\rvert = \lvert z\rvert^n$ quickly gives the result. A necessary condition for $z$ to be a root of unity is $\lvert z\rvert = 1$.

Comment: In the case you mention, the norm is wrong.  Any root of unity has norm $1$.  Now, if you take a complex number $\omega$ of norm $1$, well that's just a point on the unit circle, hence it corresponds to some angle $\theta$.  You want to know if $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$...not so easy without explicit information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any real $a$,
$x
=e^{i\pi a}
=\cos(\pi a)+i\sin(\pi a)
$
so
$|x| = 1$.

Therefore,
since
$|uv| = |u| |v|$
for any complex $u$ and $v$,
then,
 for any complex $c$
and real $a$,
$|c e^{i\pi a}|
=|c| |e^{i\pi a}|
=|c|
$.

Therefore,
if
$|c| 
\ne 1$,
$c e^{i\pi a}
$
can not be a root of unity.

Comment: But a has to be an integer in your example?

Comment: No. Any real will work.